# Function not free-ing in time

Tags: c, malloc, free, valgrind

I've had a look at a few other questions on SO but none of them seem to address a similar problem.

I have a function which sorts an array (using heap sort) and calculates the median. The heap sort routine has been taken directly from Numerical Recipies.

I am `calloc`ing and `free`ing an array inside the median function, but `free` doesn't seem to be freeing up the space in time. Here's some code to illustrate what I mean :

```
int calcMedian(int n1, int n2, int *dat) 
{
   int ii, npt;
   int *inparr, retval;

   npt    = n2 - n1 + 1; /* Number of elements in array */
   inparr = calloc(npt+1, sizeof(*inparr));

   for(ii = n1; ii <= n2; ii++)
      inparr[ii-n1+1] = dat[ii]; /* ii-n1+1 because heapsort function likes arrays to
                                 start from 1 */

   heapsortInt(npt, inparr); /* The error isn't here, function has been previously 
                                debugged. Sorting is in-place.*/
   if (npt % 2)
      retval = inparr[(npt+1)/2];
   else
      retval = (inparr[npt/2]+inparr[npt/2+1])/2;

   free(inparr);
   return(retval);
}
```

The function `heapsortInt` has been quite thoroughly debugged and has been used in several other places without issue. Now I call my function `calcMedian` in a loop like so :

```
for(ii = 0; ii < maxval; ii++) {
   index = ii * maxpt;
   med1 = calcMedian(index, index+npt1[ii]-1, data1+index);
   med2 = calcMedian(index, index+npt2[ii]-1, data2+index);
}
```

where the relevant variables are defined below :

```
int *data1, *data2;
int *npt1, *npt2;

data1 = calloc(maxval * maxpt, sizeof(*data1));
data2 = calloc(maxval * maxpt, sizeof(*data2));

npt1  = calloc(maxval, sizeof(*npt1));
npt2  = calloc(maxval, sizeof(*npt2));
```

So I'm basically passing different sections of one large array into `calcMedian` and getting back the necessary median values.

**THE PROBLEM:** `calcMedian` seems to be crashing when it hits the second function call. I ran it through valgrind, and this is what it told me:

```
Invalid read of size 4
at 0x43F67E: calcMedian /* Line no. pointing to calloc in calcMedian */
by 0x4416C9: main /* Line no pointing to second call of calcMedian */
Address 0x128ffdc0 is 6,128 bytes inside a block of size 110,788 free'd 
at 0x4A063F0: free
by 0x43F728: calcMedian /* Line no. pointing to free in calcMedian */
by 0x4416C9: main /* Line no pointing to first call of calcMedian */
```

Is this a problem with `free`? Am I `free`ing and `calloc`ing too frequently? I don't know where to start debugging this. Any help will be wonderful!

**DISCLAIMER:** The computer with the actual code cannot access the internet. I've reproduced here as accurately as I can the code that causes the problem. If there are any missing semicolons etc. that's my fault, it definitely isn't there in the original code.

Edit: Fixed some transcription errors. I'll try and get the original code up ASAP, but from me looking through both of them now this seems to be fine.

Comment: `free` always frees "in time".  Without a true [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), it's hard to give any specific advice here...

Comment: Your problem is mots likely an index out of bounds. `index+npt1[ii]-1` or another is probably calculating an out of bound memory address that by chance points to valid, but recently freed memory. On a side note: use stack arrays instead of `calloc` unless your array has to persist beyond the scope that allocated it or those arrays are multiple megabytes large.

Comment: You might screw up the memory, at which point `free` might also become unreliable if the metadata is corrupted.

Comment: @SergeyL.: However, Valgrind *should* be catching out-of-bounds accesses, etc., if they're occurring.  (Also, Valgrind is useless for stack arrays...)

Comment: There seem to be a number of bugs here which are probably transcription errors (otherwise Valgrind would be picking them up).  For example, you're allocating `maxpt` elements in `npt1`, but trying to access `maxval` elements.  Also, the bug spotted by @Klas in the answer below.  I think we *really* need to see *real* code here.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - Sorry about that! I'm having some trouble getting the code from the other machine, but I'll get that up ASAP! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the call to calcMedian.

You are adding index twice, once in the call, and then inside calcMedian.

It should be like this:

```
med1 = calcMedian(index, index+npt1[ii]-1, data1); 
med2 = calcMedian(index, index+npt2[ii]-1, data2);
```

Comment: Seems reasonable.  So the remaining question is: why is Valgrind (apparently) not reporting the resulting out-of-bounds accesses?  Oh, and how is it resulting in the error report that *is* being reported?

Comment: Shucks, that was it! I feel like an idiot now. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - I think what's happening is that because of the initial index that I was passing, the array started somewhere in the middle and reported the error once the array was out of bounds. So I'd see it only halfway through the `calcMedian` loop.